# Update cell color using Google Sheets Node.js API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to change the color of cells/text color/borders in a google sheet using Node.js. I have some data, and I want to put that data in the sheet and highlight certain rows based on conditions. The putting in data part works when I use `sheets.spreadsheets.values.update`. As a basic test for highlighting, I tried just changing some attributes of cell A1 like this:

```js
sheets.spreadsheets
    .batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: masterOrderSheetID,
        resource: {
            requests: [
                {
                    updateCells: {
                        start: {
                            sheetId: 0,
                            rowIndex: 0,
                            columnIndex: 0,
                        },
                        fields: '*',
                        rows: [
                            {
                                values: [
                                    {
                                        effectiveValue: {
                                            stringValue: 'hello please',
                                        },
                                        effectiveFormat: {
                                            backgroundColor: {
                                                red: 1,
                                                green: 0,
                                                blue: 0,
                                                alpha: 0.5,
                                            },
                                            backgroundColorStyle: {
                                                rgbColor: {
                                                    red: 1,
                                                    green: 0,
                                                    blue: 0,
                                                    alpha: 0.5,
                                                },
                                            },
                                            textRotation: {
                                                angle: 45,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ],
            includeSpreadsheetInResponse: true,
            responseIncludeGridData: true,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

but all that happens is that the formatting on cell A1 gets reset (I manually set it to bold, and it un-set the boldness). The value does not get set to `'hello please'`.

How do you set the color of a cell (or range of cells)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following suggestions?

## Suggestion 1:

Modify `fields` in your request body as follows:

### From:

```
fields: '*',
```

### To:

```
fields: 'effectiveValue,effectiveFormat',
```

## Suggestion 2:

Modify `fields`, `effectiveValue` and `effectiveFormat` in your request body as follows. (`effectiveValue` and `effectiveFormat` are modified to `userEnteredValue` and `userEnteredFormat`, respectively.)

### From:

```
fields: '*',
rows: [
    {
        values: [
            {
                effectiveValue: {
                    stringValue: 'hello please',
                },
                effectiveFormat: {
```

### To:

```
fields: 'userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat"',
rows: [
    {
        values: [
            {
                userEnteredValue: {
                    stringValue: 'hello please',
                },
                userEnteredFormat: {
```

### Reference:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: Thank you for the help Tanaike. I left `fields` part as `'*'`, but I changed `effectiveFormat` to `userEnteredFormat` and it worked. Another issue I had was that I was calling `sheets.spreadsheets.values.update` (to set some values) and `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` (to set some colors) right after each other without `await` or `.then()`. So after making these changes, I am able to set the colors properly :)

Comment: @nullromo Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your 1st question was resolved. About your 2nd question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of it and your goal? If you can do, can you provide the sample image of output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about them. Can you cooperate to resolve your 2nd question? I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Oh, there was only 1 question, and that was just how to set the colors. It wasn't working with `effectiveFormat`, but it worked with `userEnteredFormat`. The rest of what I need for my use case I can figure out on my own. Thanks again for the help; consider the question to be answered. And no need to apologize for your English skills. I am understanding what you mean :)

Comment: @nullromo Thank you for replying. If my answer was useful, I'm glad.